# How to write Peewee query that allows for variable to be pass through

Tags: python, peewee

I know that this will delete a row in my db

```
query = Staging.delete().where(Staging.branch_name == "feature")
```

I want to be able to pass a variable through query I tried:
test= feature

```
 query = f"Staging.delete().where(Staging.branch_name == "{test}")"
```

```
query = f"Staging.delete().where(Staging.branch_name == \"{test}\")"
```

```
query = "Staging.delete().where(Staging.branch_name == '{}'").format(test)
```

```
query = 'Staging.delete().where(Staging.branch_name == "{}")'.format(test)
```

```
 query = Staging.delete().where(Staging.branch_name == test)
```

These might say they deleted the row but when i check the db it is still there. Is it possible?

Comment: That does not do a query, it just creates a string.

Comment: And why don't you just replace `"feature"` with a variable?

Comment: @KlausD. thanks after tweaking  my code and adding the execute back it worked...thank you